# Is there a way to duplicate and sort a table in SSMS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have an inventory table on a Microsoft SQL Server with around 550 rows of data in columns like AssetID, AssignedName, WarrantyExpires, etc. However, this data is not in any order. From what I've researched, I understand that SQL databases have no assigned order, however I would like to order the database by AssetID to make it easier to find certain rows when I need to go into the server and edit them. The original table has a primary key called 'id' that increases by 1. What can I run in SSMS to achieve this?

I know how to copy the data from one table to a new table by runnning:
`SELECT * INTO Computers2 FROM Computers`
and I've tried adding:
`ORDER BY AssetID ASC`
but the new table is in the same order as the original table.

Comment: Like you said, tables have no assigned order. You can't make it have an order. What's wrong with simply adding an `order by` to your queries when you want to sort the data?

Comment: A table (not a database) has no order - a table is a relational *set*, you apply an order when you *query* your data.

Comment: @Isolated The guy who made the inventory database just got let go, and neither me or the new head IT guy have any SQL experience. The old IT guy used to manually go into the table on SSMS to change things instead of using any queries, and we would like to not have to be searching through 500 rows of data to find things while we figure out a better solution.

Comment: There is no way to "manually go into the table to change things" to make queries without order by return in a guaranteed order except through dumb luck. If you want to order by a specific column or set of columns to make searching easier, then `ORDER BY {those columns}`.

Comment: He would manually change things? Sounds like a good reason to pick up some new SQL skills then. Look into `where` and `order by` and `update` as a place to start. Should be able to find some good online practice areas and/or books. There's [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) where you can create your own tables, write queries, etc for practice.

Comment: You're probably better off learning about `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `INSERT` statements (CRUD) than continuing to manipulate the data by editing rows through SSMS.

You won't then have to search through anything, rather you can have the engine do it for you. https://www.sqlshack.com/crud-operations-in-sql-server/

Comment: Running these types of queries does have some risk though (when starting out pretty much everyone forgets or messes up a `WHERE` clause on an Update or Delete at some point). And I'm assuming you are making these changes direct to the production database? If so you need to make sure that you have an environment where you can test them first and appropriate backups on prod so you can do a point in time restore if you do mess up

Comment: Sounds like what you actually need is an index, possibly a clustered one.

Answer (score -5):

With some tricks you can achieve that.

But databases don't work that way - as you already noticed result sets and table are by nature unsorted.

But you don't need it as as table a view like the second sample shows will do it as well.

```
CREATE TABLE computer (id int, name varchar(10))
```

```
INSERT INTO computer VALUES(2,'A'), (5,'A'),(01,'A'),(3,'A')
```

> 4 rows affected

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT TOP 3900000000 * FROM computer order by id)
SELECT * INTO computers2 FROM CTE
```

> 4 rows affected

```
SELECT * FROM computers2
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | A |
| 5 | A |

```
CREATE VIEW mycomputers
AS
SELECT TOP 3900000000 *
FROM computer
ORDER BY id
```

```
SELECT * FROM mycomputers
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | A |
| 5 | A |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5nxhen7W)

## So as the mist can not understand the answer i will expand it

First a sql server is deterministic, which means that every query will return the same result.(as long as there are no randomness added)

Second A table is unsorted, that is because you can delete rows and reuse the identity by updating or inserting the deleted ids, so you have a table that can have the ids in any order(which is not random)

So that is the basic principles beyond my answer.

When you run the queries without the `TOP` sql sever will get you an error, because the `ORDER BY` alone is not allowed.

for comparison mysql MAriadb ignore the `ORDER BY`

But when we add the `TOP N` the sql server will sort the table and retrieve the N rows as we wanted.

The CTE has now the Table sorted by id, independent the situation of the table before hand. A SELECT of that data will reveal this.

as the System is deterministic, this will happen **always**.

Al databases are programmed the same way to achieve the LIMIT TOP  it has to sort the data, and the sorting order will be kept.

this happens by the way also with WINDOW functions.

You can test this and will find that it works

Comment: This is not a great idea. It perpetuates the myth that you can expect order without saying so. The real answer is to add order by to the final query no matter what kind of hacks you jam into the view. This is not the right pattern to show new users imo.

Comment: he ask how he can sort rows and add it to a table or view, this is also no hack it is standard sql, as most doen't recognize it even it i.... . every sql language returns a sorted result set when you limit the number of returned rows, and so you can ad all the possible number of rows your table has. So in short sql standard no hack

Comment: No. TOP + ORDER BY dictates which rows SQL Server has to return, not in which order. That it works in some cases is luck and contains no future guarantee. It’s why TOP 100 PERCENT in a view magically vanishes from the query plan.

Comment: no the order keeps maintained, test it, as io said sql standard, that is why dynamic sql can be used, which also gives back alsways teh same result

Comment: This answer is completely *WRONG* and based on a false assumption. There is no *guarantee* of ordering if it's not explcitely specified, no matter if you have any ordering in your view/derived table/table expression. This should be deleted it is 100 percent not true.

Comment: @Stu this is based on facts as io tried to explain further, and not false assumption and if you can proof that please show me a sql server database that doesn't comply

Comment: @nbk you are the one making the claim the results are always ordered as defined in the table expression without any ordering clause on the final select statement; the onus of proof is therefore yours to provide - as mentioned elsewhere I would gladly like to be pointed to a citation from the documentation, however this is a *known fact* about relational database sets and ordering, for example [this blog](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2020/04/why-ordering-isnt-guaranteed-without-an-order-by/)

Comment: One such case that can break your results if you *rely* on the output from ordering in a view is, for esample, if the query goes parallel; Imagine the optimiser chooses a parallel plan and splits the work of retrieving rows roughly evenly over 4 threads - each thread will sort its rows, but when the parallel work is recombined, thread 3 finishes before thread 4 and 2, and thread 1 finishes last; without a final *order by*, THAT is how your results will be returned from the query.

Comment: Your `SELECT ... INTO computers2` will create a heap. A heap doesn't have any particular order. The first 8 pages will be allocated from mixed extents and then subsequent pages from uniform extents. There is no guarantee that these pages and extents will be in any particular order in a file or even in the same file. Nor is there any guarantee that a subsequent `SELECT` without an `ORDER BY` will return results in any particular order without an  `ORDER BY`

Comment: @MartinSmith i created 10000 Rows with  random sorting and when i run my query the keep the sequential sorting, that i can repeat woth 1000000 and it would still give me the same result, thte system is deterministic  and would not change the order and teh select after the cte will keeo the sorting fro the WITH clause

Comment: It doesn't take a whole lot of imagination to coerce SQL Server into producing [this query plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0Pez.png), for example, which demonstrates exactly what @Stu mentioned.