# Selecting column from a table with different orders

Tags: sql, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table customer. The table has columns `cust_id`, `member`, `date`. The cust_id is a primary key (auto-increment), member can have either 1 or 0 and date contains the timestamp. I want to run a query on MySQL which let me select the cust_id with the member = 1 and order by date and then select cust_id with member = 0 and order by cust_id. Both should be in decending order (means from latest or biggest to oldest or smallest). I have tried UNION but the SQL gave error as the column date does not exist.

```
SELECT `cust_id` FROM `customer` WHERE `member` = 1 ORDER BY `date` DESC
SELECT `cust_id` FROM `customer` WHERE `member` = 0 ORDER BY `cust_id` DESC
```

I want to merge the result of these 2 queries.

I am expecting an output like this:

| cust_id | member | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 1 | 2022-05-01 22:22:22 |
| 30 | 1 | 2021-01-11 05:23:11 |
| 50 | 0 | 2023-09-01 22:22:22 |
| 49 | 0 | 2023-08-21 20:20:20 |
| 46 | 0 | 2023-08-20 19:20:21 |

but i think i am missing something.

Plese help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parthesis in MySQL to get it to work

```
CREATE tABLe customer ( `cust_id` int,`member` int,`date` datetime)
```

```
INSERT INTO customer
    (`cust_id`, `member`, `date`)
VALUES
    (25, 1, '2022-05-01 22:22:22'),
    (30, 1, '2021-01-11 05:23:11'),
      (31, 1, '2022-05-01 21:22:22'),
    (32, 1, '2021-01-11 06:23:11'),
    (50, 0, '2023-09-01 22:22:22'),
    (49, 0, '2023-08-21 20:20:20'),
    (46, 0, '2023-08-20 19:20:21'),
      (50, 0, '2023-09-01 22:22:22'),
    (51, 0, '2023-08-21 20:20:20'),
    (52, 0, '2023-08-20 19:20:21')
;
```

> ```
> Records: 10  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
(SELECT `cust_id`,`member`,`date` FROM `customer` WHERE `member` = 1 ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 10000000)
UNION 
(SELECT `cust_id`,`member`,`date` FROM `customer` WHERE `member` = 0 ORDER BY `cust_id` DESC  LIMIT 10000000)
```

| cust_id | member | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 1 | 2022-05-01 22:22:22 |
| 31 | 1 | 2022-05-01 21:22:22 |
| 32 | 1 | 2021-01-11 06:23:11 |
| 30 | 1 | 2021-01-11 05:23:11 |
| 52 | 0 | 2023-08-20 19:20:21 |
| 51 | 0 | 2023-08-21 20:20:20 |
| 50 | 0 | 2023-09-01 22:22:22 |
| 49 | 0 | 2023-08-21 20:20:20 |
| 46 | 0 | 2023-08-20 19:20:21 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rOTD0Zri)

Comment: Got it! thanks @nbk bro.. just one more thing.. the second select query orders from the smallest cust_id.. how to make it order from the biggest one?

Comment: no DESC would first show the highest id

Comment: yeah i know.. but it ain't working here.. 

Comment: that is because you the orders will be ignored, see my changed answer

Comment: Why does it work if i add the limits? a table can contain millions of values. I can't change the limit or set somthing like 1000000000

Comment: that is complicated, it follows my descrition here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76980312/is-there-a-way-to-duplicate-and-sort-a-table-ini-ssms/76980385#76980385 but as you see it was not well received, but you make two tem tables in my query here, but you could also use CTEs

Answer (score 0):

Select all and sort by member and date:

```sql
SELECT cust_id FROM customer ORDER BY member DESC, date DESC
```